# How to filter text after some stop word?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a text. From each line I want to filter everything after some stop word. For example :

`stop_words=['with','is', '/']`

One of the rows is:

`senior manager with experience`

I want to remove everything after `with` (including `with`) so the output is:

```
senior manager
```

I have big-data and am working with Spark in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the location of the stop words using `instr`, and get a substring up to that location.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

stop_words = ['with', 'is', '/']

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['senior manager with experience'],
    ['is good'],
    ['xxx//'],
    ['other text']
]).toDF('col')
df.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------+
|col                           |
+------------------------------+
|senior manager with experience|
|is good                       |
|xxx //                        |
|other text                    |
+------------------------------+

df2 = df.withColumn('idx',
    F.coalesce(
        # Get the smallest index of a stop word in the string
        F.least(*[F.when(F.instr('col', s) != 0, F.instr('col', s)) for s in stop_words]),
        # If no stop words found, get the whole string
        F.length('col') + 1)
).selectExpr('trim(substring(col, 1, idx-1)) col')

df2.show() 
+--------------+
|           col|
+--------------+
|senior manager|
|              |
|           xxx|
|    other text|
+--------------+
```

Comment: nice idea. what is `F`? Should I define step_words like this step_words=['with','is', '/']?

Comment: I still have a problem with cutting after `/` . and some other notation. in lambda did you put space?

Comment: when something is in the beginning of the line it doesn't work. Also '/' .

Comment: what subject should I search for?

Comment: @elham I've added a more robust approach to the problem. See if it works? You don't need to add spaces to the stop words.

Comment: Thanks but still there are some problems. with / and - and ...

Comment: Manager/Developer ,   Sitecore Developer - Hardrock Casino    ,

Comment: yes, but I didn't. Also Sales Representative / Home Agent

Comment: no I didn't. for example for Patient Coordinator - Orthodontic Associates   I get Patient C

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227039/discussion-between-mck-and-elham).

Comment: how we can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use udf and get index of first occurrence of stop word in col, then again using one more udf, you can substring col message.

```
val df = List("senior manager with experience", "is good", "xxx//", "other text").toDF("col")

val index_udf = udf ( (col_value :String ) =>  {val result = for (elem <- stop_words; if col_value.contains(elem)) yield col_value.indexOf(elem)
     if (result.isEmpty)  col_value.length else result.min } )
val substr_udf = udf((elem:String, index:Int) => elem.substring(0, index))
val df3 = df.withColumn("index", index_udf($"col")).withColumn("substr_message", substr_udf($"col", $"index")).select($"substr_message").withColumnRenamed("substr_message", "col")
df3.show()

+---------------+
|            col|
+---------------+
|senior manager |
|               |
|            xxx|
|     other text|
+---------------+
```